# Delete Spotify playlist programmatically

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

Is it possible to delete a Spotify playlist using the JS API? I've created hundreds in error, but the API doesn't seem to have any obvious way of removing them.

Comment: According to the documentation there doesn't seem to be any way to delete a playlist.

Comment: There is still no way to do this programically? I am creating web GUI for managing playlists, and I would love to have option to remove whole bunch of playlists...

Answer (score 3):

This answer comes late, but it solves the problem and can be useful to users with the same problem. One can "unfollow" a playlist (even his own!), which has the effect of deleting it from one's Spotify account. The relevant function is `user_playlist_unfollow(user, playlist_id)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it's really tedious.

See: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models-collection.html

```
myTracks.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
  myTracks.remove(snapshot.find(track));
});
```

replace "track" with playlist.  You need something like:

```
library.forCurrentUser().playlists.snapshot(0,1).done(function(s) {
  library.forCurrentUser().playlists.remove(s.find(s.get(0)));
}
```

The gotacha here is that if you try to run this in a loop it will fail since the snapshot is stale the 2nd time it runs... very annoying.